# PHP Website - Loading Stylesheets in Sub Directories

Tags: php, css, html

I'm building a PHP based site with this directory structure

> index.php
>
> > **css**
> >
> > > - style.css
> > > - bootstrap.css
> >
> > **includes**
> >
> > > - header.php
> > > - footer.php
> >
> > **bikes**
> >
> > > - road.php
> > > - mountain.php

### The Problem

So I'm working on **road.php** and I obviously need to be able to link to both **style.css** and **bootstrap.css**, but when I declare at the start of **road.php** to include the **header.php** and **footer.php** it is like as if it cannot find the stylesheets and the site reverts back to the default 1990s look.

I have also found that any form of link on the page loads a 404. I'm only just starting out with PHP because I need some more power in my sites, but I just can't seem to get my head around the super basic things.

I just don't know what to do and I'm finding myself turning my back on the whole PHP language.

Thanking you in advance,

Stu :)

Comment: try using absolute urls `/css/style.css` (assuming your index.php is at site root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be certain without seeing the actual content of `header.php` (in perticular the part where you import the stylesheets), but it sounds like you are using a relative path to your stylesheets. Something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />`. This works fine for `index.php`, but since the other pages are inside the subfolder `bikes`, they will be looking for the CSS files in `yoursite.com/bikes/css`.

The solution is to provide an absolute path. Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yoursite.com/css/style.css" media="screen" />
```

This way, it doesn't matter if the page is inside a subfolder (or a subfolder of a subfolder) - it will allways look for the CSS file in the right location.

If you are using multiple domain names, or for some other reason you cannot hardcode the domain name, you can prepend a slash (`/`) to the path as well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" media="screen" />
```

This path is relative to the root of the website, not to the current directory.

Comment: I have found that
`<link href="<?php echo $SERVER['SERVER NAME']; ?>../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<link href="<?php echo $SERVER['SERVER NAME']; ?>../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` works but I'm not 100% sure if this is good practice.

Comment: I have made a small update to my answer... if you cannot (or don't want to) hardcode the domain name in the URL's, you can use relative paths that start with a slash. That way they're relative to the current domain name / site root, instead of relative to the current directory.

Comment: If you want to put the css call in header.php, you should make relative url to the css. This should work `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" media="screen" />`
Notice the _.._ is to told the url up one level to its parent folder.

Comment: @wiratama that will not work, `header.php` is included by all other pages throughout the site. Thus all HTML output will contain `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" media="screen" />`, regardless of the (sub)directory they are located in. The path (`../css/style.css`) is relative to the URL of the page, not to the `/includes` directory, because the browser has no knowlegde of PHP includes.